# FB Request output not working in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

My FB Request output not working in iOS. It outputs twice to the console. the first time it outputs the correct info and then immediately does the same thing with (null) instead of the correct data.

here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"fbKEY....." andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

//FB check for valid session


if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_likes", 
                            @"read_stream",
                            @"user_location",
                            @"user_checkins",
                            //    @"publish_actions",
                            //    @"user_activities",
                            //    @"friends_birthday",
                            nil];

    [facebook authorize:permissions];

}


[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];


// get the posts made by the "platform" page
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"platform/posts" andDelegate:self];

// get the logged-in user's friends
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
```

}

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result { 

NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result; // The result is a dictionary

NSString *name = [userData objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *location = [[userData objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *gender = [userData objectForKey:@"gender"];

NSLog(@"name is %@", name);
NSLog(@"location is %@", location);

NSLog(@"gender is %@", gender);

// NSLog(@"%@",result); 

}
```

here's my NSLog output:

```
2012-04-04 16:42:56.440 Whatto[86350:15803] name is John Doe
2012-04-04 16:42:56.441 appName[86350:15803] location is London
2012-04-04 16:42:56.441 appName[86350:15803] gender is male
2012-04-04 16:42:56.688 appName[86350:15803] name is (null)
2012-04-04 16:42:56.688 appName[86350:15803] location is (null)
2012-04-04 16:42:56.689 appName[86350:15803] gender is (null)
2012-04-04 16:42:58.696 appName[86350:15803] name is (null)
2012-04-04 16:42:58.697 appName[86350:15803] location is (null)
2012-04-04 16:42:58.697 appName[86350:15803] gender is (null)
```

thanks for any help

Comment: You have to show more code. Particularly the methods where you create the requests

Comment: I added the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions methods.

Comment: Have you actually tried breakpointing on the `request didLoad` method and inspecting the contents of what's coming back from Facebook? That would probably tell you what the problem is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making 3 different requests and treating the result like every answer is a user...
The second result will be a list of posts and the third will be a list of friends.

Good luck!